# Angular Table Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an api that gets called on page load. The data from the api is loaded into a table via angular ng-repeat. I also have a javascript function that gets called every 10 seconds that calls the same api for the same dataset. I Would like to know how i can apply the new dataset to the table and replace the old if the dataset changes and how to visually show this change with animation. The code is below.

Table code

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ScansController">
<div class="bs-example" id="scan-table">
    <table id="scansTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ScanId</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="scan in Scans">
                <td>
                    {{scan.scanId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.firstName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.lastName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.timeStamp}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascipt interval code**

```
<script>
  window.setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/scans/',
        type: 'Get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {                
        //Something here
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("something failed");
        }
     });

    }, 10000);
</script>
```

**Angular Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

this.getData = function () {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/scans/'
    });
}
});

myApp.controller('ScansController', function ($scope, dataService) {
$scope.Scans = [];

    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {
        $scope.Scans = result.data;
        console.log(result.data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: When there is a change in the model it will automatically have impact on the view Right?Angular will take care of that?
https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/pPU4m/
see this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stay inside the current scope.

Setting an interval on a `$http` call is poison. Use a `$timeout` inside the success callback to recursively call the next interval.

```
myApp.controller('ScansController', function ($scope, $timeout, dataService) {

  $scope.Scans = [];

  function fetchData(){
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {
      $scope.Scans = result.data;
      $timeout(function(){ fetchData(); },10000);
    });   
  }

  fetchData();
});
```

Comment: this code works on the initial load, but doesnt make the call again after 10 seconds

Comment: sorry i didnt see that you injected $timeout

Comment: @Monzingo Accept / upvote the answer if it's helped your issue.

Comment: i upvoted for the code adjustment, i guess i still need a way to check to see if there is a difference and if there is, animate that difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the table refresh that didnt get addressed, this is how i was able to make it work. I downloaded and applied the animate.css. I then gave the table a starting class to animate it on class load. I then have a function that fetches the array of data on page load and then another that fetches every .5 seconds and compares. If anything has changed, then the class is reapplied and it shows animation.

**Angular Ng-Repeat Table**

```
<link href="~/Content/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h1>
Scans
</h1>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ScansController" >   
    <table id="scansTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ScanId</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="scan in Scans" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="animated bounceIn">
                <td>
                    {{scan.scanId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.firstName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.lastName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{scan.timeStamp}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('dataService', function ($http) {

this.getData = function () {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/scans/'
    });
}
});

myApp.controller('ScansController', function ($scope, dataService, $timeout) {

$scope.Scans = [];
$scope.NewScans = [];

function fetchData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {

        $scope.Scans = result.data;
        $("#scansTable").removeClass('animated bounceIn');           
    });
}

function fetchNewData() {
    dataService.getData().then(function (result) {

        $scope.NewScans = result.data;

        if ($scope.Scans.length != $scope.NewScans.length)
        {               
            $("#scansTable").addClass('animated bounceIn');
            $scope.Scans = $scope.NewScans              
        }

        $timeout(function () { fetchNewData(); }, 500);
    });
}

fetchData();
fetchNewData();

});
```